# C# strongly typed ConfigurationBuilder List<object> from appsettings

Tags: c#, .net-core, console-application, .net-core-configuration

Really struggling with this one - is it supposed to be this hard?!

I have a simple object array in my appsettings:

```
"AppSettings": {
    "Names": [
      {
        "Id": "1",
        "Name": "Mike"
      },
      {
        "Id": "2",
        "Name": "John"
      }    
    ]
}
```

I then have a class

```
public class AppSettings
{
    public List<Names> Names { get; set; } = new List<Names>();
}

public class Names
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

I read in my app settings:

```
var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                            .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                            .AddJsonFile("appSettings.json").Build();

var config = new AppSettings();
```

This is where stuff goes wrong:

```
config.Names = configuration.GetSection("AppSettings:Names") //<<<< what do I do here?
```

It seems like it's all tied to `IConfigurationSection` which is not helpful.

Comment: `var config = new AppSettings(); Configuration.GetSection("AppSettings").Bind(config);` It should work alike for just the names section if you prefer that

Comment: Yeh have tried this as there was a lot about binding online, this is what I get:
"Cannot implicitly convert type 'void' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<Names.Names>"

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Get the entire object graph from the setting using the `ConfigurationBinder.Get<T>` extension.

> `ConfigurationBinder.Get<T>` binds and returns the specified type. `ConfigurationBinder.Get<T>` may be more convenient than using `ConfigurationBinder.Bind`. The following code shows how to use `ConfigurationBinder.Get<T>` with the `AppSettings` class:

```
//...

AppSettings config = configuration.GetSection("AppSettings").Get<AppSettings>();

//...
```

Reference [Configuration in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/#bind-hierarchical-configuration-data-using-the-options-pattern)